# Possible memory leak in string memory allocation

Tags: c++, string, memory-leaks, stl

This is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string & fileread(const char * name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(name,"rb");
    size_t sz;
    int i;
    char *buff;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);  
    sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(sz+1));
    buff[sz] = '\0';
    fread(buff,sz,1,fp); 
    std::string * rtstr = new std::string(buff);
    free(buff);
    fclose(fp);
    return * rtstr;
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    std::string file_info(fileread(argv[1]));
    std::cout<<file_info << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is simply read one file, and print its content to screen.

In the function `fileread`, I use `new std::string(buff);` to get a `std::string *`, and return the point back. Will it cause memory leak? And if the answer is 'yes' , how to avoid it?

---

About use C in C++: `fread` is much faster than `ifstream` (tested with 1 billion random number)

My problem is about memory leak.

Comment: DONT code C in C++. Use `std::ifstream` and `std::string` (not `std::string*`).

Comment: `fread()` is as fast as `std::ifstream::read()` is. So again, DONT think C wins when comes to performance. C++ is equally good, and in some cases, *better performant than C*.

Comment: @Nawaz Please share some good links for "better performant than C".

Comment: @SahilSareen C++ type system encourages static type checking and value semantics, both of these result in better optimizations. Consider `std::sort()` vs `qsort()` for example: C is based on function pointers (One of the worst enemies of CPUs pipelines), C++ on the other hand, is based on templates and functors (aka the compiler inlines everything).

Comment: @SahilSareen: Compare ANY code generic C code which uses pointers (often `void*` and function pointers) with generic C++ code which uses templates. C++ is most likely to be faster than C. One such example is `std::sort` (from C++ standard library) vs `qsort` (from C standard library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return std::string by value. Don't worry, C++ will take care of not copying the object redundantly (unless you have a very old compiler). 
Here is the code, fixed:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string fileread(const char * name)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(name,"rb");
    size_t sz;
    int i;
    char *buff;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);  
    sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(sz+1));
    buff[sz] = '\0';
    fread(buff,sz,1,fp); 
    std::string rtstr(buff);
    free(buff);
    fclose(fp);
    return * rtstr;
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    std::string file_info(fileread(argv[1]));
    std::cout<<file_info << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I made only the small change necessary and ignored any other problems you might have in your code. Take care.

Comment: `[yu@argcv ex]$ g++ test.cc --std=c++11
test.cc: In function ‘std::string fileread(const char*)’:
test.cc:22:12: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
     return * rtstr;
            ^
`

Comment: if just return rtstr, it returns a local value.

Comment: @YuJing: It returns a copy, not the reference to the local variable.

Comment: @Nawaz and , I may read 1GB or more `binary` data from file,would you please give more some more better suggestion ?

Comment: The line `return * rtstr;` needs to be replaced with `return rtstr;` Any modern compiler will perform return value optimization so no copy will be made.

Comment: If the data contains null bytes then `std::string rtstr(buff);` will cut off data after the null byte. Use `std::string rtstr(buff, sz);` or maybe consider using `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Nawaz rightly commented: "DONT code C in C++. Use std::ifstream and std::string (not std::string*)". Here is the code in C++ to avoid all the issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("myfile.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to use `myfile.close()`. Also, `if (myfile)`  is better than `if (myfile.is_open())`.

Comment: @Nawaz I used it to close it properly. Is it not a good practice to do so?

Comment: It will close the file, when the stream object goes out of scope. It is RAII object. So no worries.

Comment: @SahilSareen: See [my question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/540/my-c-code-involving-an-fstream-failed-review) regarding this exact issue.

Comment: `std::getline` is probably not suitable if he intends to read binary data